# Filling MySql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm building a database using MySql, I want to fill it with data. What is the best way to fill its tables using Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "MySQL java connector"?

Comment: The answer below tells you what I mean by the connector.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Answer (score 4):

You could use a JDBC connector to connect your application to MySQL .You might need to download a JDBC connector if you don't have one.

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("localhost", username, password);
        String sql = "select * from table_name";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

you could use `rs.getString(1)` to return the data in the first column and `rs.getString(2)` from the second column and so on...

If the value in the first column is a string then you use `rs.getString()` , if it's an int you use `rs.getInt()` and similarly for other datatypes . A good Google search would give you other options.

If you were to do an **`insert`** statement then you  will have to replace `stmt.executeQuery(sql)` with **`stmt.executeUpdate(sql)`**

Here are two good tutorials that will get you started

http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/insertvalues.shtml

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` is often the fastest way to import bulk data.

Comment: Yes your right. But his questions is not clear on what type of data he has ? maybe he just wants to run an insert statement.

Comment: If it can be put into rows and columns, `LOAD DATA INFILE` has you covered.

Answer (score 0):

There is ResourceDatabasePopulator in Spring JDBC. It can populate a database from SQL scripts defined in external resources. Prepare a script with INSERT statements and run it from Java as

```
Connection conn = ...
ResourceDatabasePopulator dbp = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
dbp.addScript(new FileSystemResource("test.sql"));
dbp.populate(conn);
```